# Facebook PHP SDK fatal error occures Facebook:: throwAPIException

Tags: facebook-graph-api, exception, facebook-php-sdk, fatal-error

```
    try {
        $return = $facebook->api("/" . $userFromDB["username"] . "/feed",
            "post", array(
                message => "",
                picture => "http://blabla.net/blabla1/img/autopost/" . $blabla2 . ".png",
                link => "http://apps.facebook.com/blabla1/?var2=" . $encryptedUserIds[$userFromDB["id"]], //$appPageURL
                caption => "Tikla, begen.",
                description => $var3,
                access_token => $auth["auth_code"],
            ));
        $usersPosted++;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $userProcessError++;
        write_log("blabla");
    }
```

Hello, this is the part of the code where i send posts to users' wall. If there is no exception, the code works flawlessly. Whenever an exception occures, I get this annoying fatal error.

I have tried many things to correct but the script is the same where I make calls to facebook api in other parts of my code.

I searched google and stackoverflow. Noone seems to have this error. Am i the only one? Thanks in advance.

This is the error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Facebook::throwAPIException() in facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 870
```

Facebook sdk version i use: 3.2
Php version: 5.3

EDIT: this is how i get access_token for user. I store it into db:

```
 

    if(isset($code) && $state==$authState){
        $accessTokenInformation=file_get_contents($accessTokenURL . $code);
        $tmpResult=explode("&", $accessTokenInformation);

        if(sizeof($tmpResult)==2){
            $tmpAT=explode("=", $tmpResult[0]);
            $tmpExp=explode("=", $tmpResult[1]);

            if(sizeof($tmpAT)==2 && sizeof($tmpExp)==2){
                $tmpDBUserAuth=check_db_for_authcode_for_user(...);
                if(empty($tmpDBUserAuth)){
                    insert_authcode_indb(...);
                    write_log(...);
                }else{
                    update_authcode_indb(...)
                    write_log(...);
                }

            }else{
                write_log(...);
                echo(' top.location.href="'. $OAuthURL .'"; ');
            }
        }else{
            write_log(...);
            echo(' top.location.href="'. $OAuthURL .'"; ');
        }
    }
```

EDIT on 2012/11/06: Problem still persists. Please help.

Comment: How are you getting the authcode? Are you using `$facebook->getAccessToken()`?

Comment: I added the piece of code for how  get access_token. I don't use access token when user is logged in. I use it to post daily wall updates later in another script.

Comment: Access Tokens do have a shelf life, how long are you storing them?

Comment: I store them as long as the expiration time. The expiration time value is gathered with access token. If the expiration time is reached, I mark it in db as expired. Whenever user visits my app and there is code value in url. I update the access token in db. So access token renews with new expiration value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you FB API secrete keys are proper set or not ...  I also faced this problem , but i have corrected secrete keys after that it was working perfect.

Try to use the following script

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/update-login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

Comment: The facebook credentials is the same where i authorize users. And there is no exception there. I don't think this is about wrong api/secret key problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any other recommends, please?

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Facebook::throwAPIException() in facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 870

That error message does not make sense.

If I go to line 870 in that file in my IDE, and follow the method name to its declaration, it’s in the same file on line 1237 (all for current version 3.2.0).

So there is no plausible reason for a undefined method error there.

Could you please check if the SDK files got uploaded correctly to your server, or just re-download and re-upload them, to make sure its not a problem with mangled/truncated file contents?

Comment: I uploaded sdk files to my server once again. I will see if it occurs again and inform you with the results. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same fatal error if code processes invalid access token. This şs so annoying.